# Sort a string list: Move or exchange items only

Tags: delphi, sorting, pascal, tstringlist

In Delphi / Pascal I would like to sort a TStringList alphabetically. But for this purpose, I can only use the following two methods:

**Move:** Moves a string from one index position to another, shifting other strings around as appropriate.

**Exchange:** Swaps two strings in the list, as identified by their index positions.

How could I do this? I had the idea to go through all items with a loop and to something like this:

1. lastFirstLetter := Copy(CurrentItem, 1, 1)
2. go to next item
3. currentFirstLetter := Copy(CurrentItem, 1, 1)
4. if ord(currentFirstLetter) < ord(lastFirstLetter) then exchange(lastItem, currentItem)

What would be the fastest way to sort a StringList with these two methods? I can't use the sort method and the sorted property by the way.

Comment: Tagging as "homework" (sounds like it is) as it will influence any answers you get. Taking into account the fact that you should work out the actual solution for your own edification.  Good luck.

Comment: Neither do I have computer sciences in school, nor do I study this. It's just my hobby. But now I must accept that you tagged my question as "homework" ...

Comment: My apologies for the mistag.  Thank you for the clarification...removing :-)

Comment: No problem, thank you for the fast correction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move / exchange methods are all you need. However you've got a lot of algorithms to choose from! Have a look at this site (from a quick Google search) for animated comparisons: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

I think that all these algorithms just use 'move', apart from heap and the quicksorts which only use 'exchange'

Comment: Thank you very much! Probably every programmer does know this website but I didn't :D The site is great!

Answer (score 3):

You give two methods: (1) Swap and (2) Exchange.

There is a third method:

(3) Keep a TList of pointers to your strings and sort the pointers.

This method will leave all your strings where they are and could be faster.

See the question: [Best Way To Sort An Array In Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733/best-way-to-sort-an-array-in-delphi) and Barry Kelly's accepted answer as well as the other answers.